# Deleting Rows based on value from another table - T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to delete a row from a table. First of all, I have 2 Tables. I want to delete a row when, Table1.a is the same as Table2.a. Would like to get some help; I want to delete the Table2.a, sorry for bad english.

Comment: you have to show a bit more on what have, what you tried and what is not working.

Comment: i cant say much more  :/ im a intern and cant say much , but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query, to delete record from Table1 based on matching rows from Table2

```
DELETE A
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
  ON A.a=B.a
--Where A.a=B.a
```